# Magento Installer Script Not Working

Tags: php, install, script

I read all the installer script not working threads and still can't figure it out.

I want to run a simple installer script for my module eg:
community/Aquiver/Productslider1/

The install php file is:

sql/productslider1_setup/install-0.1.0.php

`echo 'Running Script: '.get_class($this)."\n";
die("Exit for now");`

and the config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Aquiver_Productslider1>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Aquiver_Productslider1>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <productslider1>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Aquiver_Productslider1</module>
                    <frontName>productslider1</frontName>
                </args>
            </productslider1>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <productslider1>
                <class>Aquiver_Productslider1_Block</class>
            </productslider1>
        </blocks>
         <helpers>
            <productslider1>
                <class>Aquiver_Productslider1_Helper</class>
            </productslider1>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <productslider1>
                <class>Aquiver_Productslider1_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>productslider1_resource</resourceModel>
            </productslider1>
            <productslider1_resource>
                <class>Aquiver_Productslider1_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <theproduct>
                        <table>theproduct</table>
                    </theproduct>
                </entities>
            </productslider1_resource>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <productslider1_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Aquiver_Productslider1</module>
                    <class>Aquiver_Productslider1_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </productslider1_setup>
        </resources>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <aquiver_productslider1 before="Mage_Adminhtml">Aquiver_Productslider1_Adminhtml</aquiver_productslider1>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

The install page never works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an installer try to follow this tutorial: http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

Make sure you clear all caches (even if they're turned off) and try your `config.xml` without

```
<resources>
    <productslider1_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>Aquiver_Productslider1</module>
            <class>Aquiver_Productslider1_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
        </setup>
    </productslider1_setup>
</resources>
```

That should still work for a basic installer script

Comment: Many thanks.. The actual problem is that I forgot to delete the core_resource field with my version in order to run the script again!